# Querying Azure AD using c# console application

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

I am developing a simple c# console application to query Azure AD and fetch details of a given user. I found many useful articles on querying azure AD but none of them served my purpose. The sample codes posted on GitHub are way too lengthy and complicated for my simple requirement.
I am using the code below, but i am getting a token error:

```
static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            /* OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit:
               https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks */



            // Specify values for the following required parameters
            queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
            // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
            // var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/users/{v-sidmis@microsoft.com}?" + queryString;

            var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/users?api-version=1.6";

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }


        }
```

I further searched for the token access and registered my app in the ad and used the below code:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("AUTHORITY");
            string token;
            try
            {
                //var authresult = authContext.AcquireToken("MYAPP_ID", "MYAPP_CLIENTID", "MYAPP_REDIRECTURI");
                var authresult = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", "23b1c65e-5a20-4b88-a474-85c0845782c7", "https://localhost/");
                token = authresult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

But not the getting the required result. Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use graph API to get User info. You need to add token to your request header like following:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", TokenForUser);
```

Here is the code snippet that could help to list User info, hope it could give you some tips:

```
 string AuthString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
 string ResourceUrl = "https://graph.windows.net";
 string ClientId = "***";
 var redirectUri = new Uri("https://localhost");
 string  TenantId = "e4162ad0-e9e3-4a16-bf40-0d8a906a06d4";

 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthString+TenantId, false);
 AuthenticationResult userAuthnResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl,
     ClientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession));
 TokenForUser = userAuthnResult.AccessToken;
 var client = new HttpClient();

 var uri = $"https://graph.windows.net/{TenantId}/users?api-version=1.6";
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", TokenForUser);
 var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
 if (response.Content != null)
 {
     var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     Console.WriteLine(responseString);
 }
```

We could find ClientId, RedirectURi, tenantId, ResourceUrl in Azure AD native application:

Comment: application id is the clientid.

Comment: Also the code is showing build errors on PlatformParameters and Token for user

Comment: Do i need any assembly reference for platformParamerters ?

Comment: Do you add this assembly `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`?

Comment: Yes I have added it.

Comment: If you go to definition of the method `AcquireTokenAsync`. Could you able to find this function: `public Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters parameters);` If you copy the code I provide, I think it should be work. Please also try to check whether your solution have this assembly `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform`. You could find the class PlatformParameters under this assembly.

Comment: No my project does not have the assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform from where can i find this? can you tell me how to install it from nugget?

Comment: We can open package manger console then run this command `Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`. Refer to [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/22da8c/package-manager-console-in-visual-studio/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient and answering my questions..I really appreciate this..I got the dll thing resolved...but I am getting the exception because of the authstring...can you come online over skype...I can show you my app settings and code...I am completely blocked!

Comment: I am getting the following exception:
Additional information: 'authority' Uri should have at least one segment in the path (i.e. https://<host>/<path>/...)

Comment: Please check the code ` AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthString, false)`. verify the AuthString is the same as in my reply.

Comment: Yes I have used the same AuthString as provided by you. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: this is the exception:'authority' Uri should have at least one segment in the path (i.e. https://<host>/<path>/...)
Parameter name: authority

Comment: Hello dotnetman, I have tested this code on my local. It seems that I have a mistake when convert some sensitive values. I get the same issue when I run the code today, and get the same error message. The correct code is `AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthString+TenantId, false);` We need add tenant ID in authority. Please try it. Sorry for my mistake. If you have any issues, welcome come back or create a new thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128899/discussion-between-dotnetman-and-jambor-msft).

Comment: When i call AcquireTokenAsync it pops up a login dialog? I'm putting this in an app specifically to automate it. How can i just programmatically handle authentication with a service account?